# At what point/range is a code file too big?

Tags: code-quality, code-smell

I'm finding lots of 2-3k line files, and it doesn't really feel like they should be that big.

What is a good criteria to objectively call a source code file "too big"?, is there such thing  as a maximum amount of lines a source code file should have?

Comment: [Your peer tells you after reviewing the code.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141010/31260) _"You cannot determine this yourself because you know more as the author than the code says by itself. A computer cannot tell you, for the same reasons that it cannot tell if a painting is art or not. Hence, you need another human - capable of maintaining the software - to look at what you have written and give his or her opinion..."_

Comment: Some compilers used to have weird limits on source code size: max line length or max number of lines. When compiler complains, this is an objective indicator that code is too big (or that it is time to upgrade).

Comment: Split as much as possible, but without breaking the integrity of files. Each file (or pair of header/source files) should always be a rounded whole, independent of the internal implementation of other files. If this means some files will be large because they implement something complex, so be it.

Comment: Note that complexity is not just about numbers, but also about structure. For example, I'd like to state the python zen "flat is better than nested": a flat list of 100 cases is simpler than a hierarchy (you won't remember all 100 cases but you easily remember that there are 100 alternatives). And a "regular" hierarchy where branches have the same structure than their siblings are simpler than hierarchy with irregular sub-structure.

Comment: "Is that the source code?"  "No, that's the makefile, The source code is in the trucks following behind".

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As an ideal model I use the following criteria (with a similar rationale to what Martin Beckett suggested, i.e. to think in terms of logical structure and not in terms of lines of code):

**Rule 1**

One class per file (in C++: one class -> one header and one implementation file).

**Rule 2**

Seven is considered the number of items that our brain can observe at the same time without getting confused. Above 7 we find it difficult to keep an overview of what we see. Therefore: each class should not have more than 7-10 methods. A class that has more than 10 method is probably too complex and you should try to split it. Splitting is a very effective method because every time you split a class you reduce the complexity of each individual class at least by a factor of 2.

**Rule 3**

A method body that does not fit in one or two screens is too big (I assume that a screen / editor window is about 50 lines). Ideally, you can see the whole method in one window. If this is not the case, you only need to scroll up and down a bit, without forgetting the part of the method that gets hidden. So, if you have to scroll more than one screen up or down to read the whole method body, your method is probably too big and you can easily lose the overview.

Again, splitting methods using private help methods can reduce method complexity very fast (at every split the complexity is at least halved). If you introduce too many private help methods you can consider creating a separate class to collect them (if you have more private methods than public ones, maybe a second class is hiding inside your main class).

Putting together these very rough estimates:

- At most one class per source file.
- At most 10 public method per class.
- At most 10 private method per class.
- At most 100 lines per method.

So a source file that is more than 2000 lines is probably too large and starting to be too messy.

This is really a very rough estimate and I do not follow these criteria systematically (especially because there is not always enough time to do proper refactoring). Also, as Martin Beckett suggested, there are situations in which a class is a large collection of methods and it does not make sense to split them in some artificial way just to make the class smaller.

Anyway, in my experience a file starts to get unreadable when one of the above parameters is not respected (e.g. a 300 line method body that spans six screens, or a source file with 5000 lines of code).

Comment: Disagree with #2: what about overloads? For example ostream << operator in C++ has a large number of similar methods, but fundamentally all do the same thing (write to the stream).

Comment: @JBRWilkinson: See the paragraph towards the end of the answer.

Comment: I would also strive for methods no more than 10 lines...helps with readability/understanding what the method is doing & reduces complexity that can easily happen in big methods...

Comment: Event-driven frameworks (like GUI systems) sometimes violate #2 on a regular basis, so I think there's an exception for those. I agree with overloads as well; I'm sure Console.WriteLine() isn't defined in multiple files.

Comment: Rule2 is absurd if you follow it to its conclusion. You should not have more than 7 files in a directory so you have to keep your files big so that you don't get confused between the tens or hundreds of files in your project. Similarly, a deeply nested directory structure is overly confusing so it's better to keep a few large files in one directory than scatter everything around.

Comment: Rule2 is based on false premise. Humans work well with more than 7 items. Otherwise even mobile phone with 10 digits would confuse us, not even saying about keyboards.

Comment: I'm sorry this answer is based on wholly arbitrary metrics. The "7 items" is clearly bullshit, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use the alphabet. The size of object should be based on separation of concerns, single-responsibility, hight-cohesion-low-coupling and similar principles, not arbitrary numbers.

Comment: @JacquesB The 7 items is usually indicative of 7 pieces of unrelated information.  If your brain can associate or group information, in a real sense it is 1 piece of information that can lead to more if you try to recall (in fact "alphabet" is a symbol, not all 26 letters).  A better example would be trying to remember a 7 digit number told to you over the phone without having pen and paper available.  Methods clearly aren't arbitrary numbers, but if those methods are relevant to what you're coding, you can expect after 7, you'll have to look for it before you can recall correctly.

Comment: @Neil: If the the methods in a class are random unrelated pieces of information, then you have bigger problems in your class design than the number of methods.

Comment: @Neil: "in a real sense it is 1 piece of information": then you probably want to give it a name and replace the different items e.g. with one function call. In this way at the higher abstraction level you only see the name and, if you want to see the details, you look up the function implementation.

Comment: I find that an intelligent editor with folding helps to reduce the information-overload that your rules of thumb combat.  Combining that kind of editor with sensible application of your rules makes for easy reading!

Comment: It's unfortunate that this is the accepted and most voted answer, as the comments indicate. I wouldn't argue so much, as it at least establishes a ballpark figure, but it should be no more than that. Martin Beckett's answer is more salient. I can think of frequent exceptions to rules 1 and 2 immediately and although rule 3 would be least frequently broken in my approach it's not because it doesn't fit on a screen, it's because that would be too much logic for 1 method. All these numbers are almost meaningless in the face of questions of the design and practical logic required.

Answer (score 39):

No - not in terms of lines of code. The driver should be logical grouping. There certainly shouldn't be multiple classes in one large file for example

If you had a class that legitmately had a few hundred methods (not impossible in say 3D modelling) it would be a lot less convenient to split that into arbitrary files. We used to have to do this when memory was scarcer and processors slower - and it was a pains, constantly searching for the function definition.

Comment: Wouldn't a class with hundreds of methods be a symptom of  class envy, lack of cohesiveness, poor design, violation of single responsibility principle, etc. ?

Comment: @user1598390: usually, but not always.

Comment: @user1598390 - common in say gis/3d modelling to have lots of operations you can perform, and then have them overloaded for 2d,3d,4d,3d+signal,then float/double/integer etc - templates help a little but for efficency lots of operations are often better than a pretty class heirarchy

Comment: I disagree with the above opinion. Hundreds of classes can be in same header file - makes searching correct class easier when you don't need to jump from one file to another.

Comment: @tp1 ... wat?!?

Comment: @dukeofgaming - either irony, or we have found the reason behind Microsoft Bob

Comment: @dukeofgaming: Yup. Hundreds of classes in one file is a good design if you have 1200 classes.

Comment: @tp1 Oh, I get it now, you are joking :D

Comment: @dukeofgaming: It's more like I don't like 1200 files floating around in the file system...

Comment: @tp1 - and you use a small font so they don't take up as much space?

Comment: @tp1 Dude, I'm sorry, I really don't mean any disrespect, but I feel sorry for whoever works with you. If you have 1200 classes, use a directory convention, if you have too many directories, split them into independent modules/libraries.

Comment: @dukeofgaming: Naah, one lib, about 30 files, 1200 classes, 10 public classes. That's the stats you should aim for.

Comment: @tp1 - you use different classes? Doesn't that make it complex remembering the names?

Comment: @Martin Beckett: No need to remember them. Only the most important common base classes need to be remembered. Then the documentation helps with using the stuff.

Comment: Depends on the size of the class. If you're writing a compiler you can put the AddOperation, SubtractOperation, MultiplyOperation and DivideOperation in the same file assuming they're relatively short.

Comment: I have to disagree, you can have access to a hundred methods via name-spacing like `engine.store.addObject(object)`, `engine.renderer.renderObject(object)` and `engine.objectLoader.load('objectId')`. That doesn't mean the `engine` has to have more than a 100 methods.

Comment: One case where I think multiple classes belong in one file:  I often find myself writing a class and a very simple container for it.  Putting the container is a separate file is needless hassle, it more properly belongs at the end of the file defining the class.

Comment: You are right about constantly searching for a function's definition.  On the other hand, there is the problem of constantly searching for the *file* in which a function is defined; but on the whole I agree with you.  However, your proscription against multiple classes is too absolute.  There exist auxiliary and preparatory classes that belong nowhere but in same file together with the main class they support.  Also, I know of one example (in my own code) of a pair of logically independent classes from which common code without external use has been refactored.  So, there are exceptions.

Answer (score 11):

When the code in it becomes unmaintainable. *i.e:* you can't tell just by watching the code if the method/class/function you're looking for (and have to edit/debug) is in there, or not, and if so, where it is.

Your IDE/Editor choice and features will influence this upper limit's actual quantification, though. **Code folding**, **function/method listing, and lookup** will *postpone* the moment this development scenario presents.

But when it does, it's time to split it.

Answer (score 10):

Consider this `Metaphor`. When it comes to code length, I think we should consider the following:

```
The Cat in The Hat (50 pp.)
```

and

```
Lord of The Rings (1,178 pp.)
```

There is nothing wrong with `Lord of the Rings`. It's a fabulous book. `The Cat in the Hat` is also a great book. Both can be understood by a 5 year olds, but only one is better suited due to content.

To my point, writing code should make sense to a 5 year old whenever we can. `Cyclomatic Complexity` is an important concept that may developers should consider as they generate code. Utilizing and creating libraries to enhance functionality and code reusability as much as possible. This way our code can speak more volumes than what we see written.

**Most of us are not writing assembly code**. But the root of our code is assembly. Searching through 10000 lines assembly is harder than 10000 lines of python, if it is done correctly.

But some work requires writing 500 to 1000 lines. Our goal with code should be to write 300 lines of clean code.

As developers, we want to write "Lord of The Rings". Until we get a bug and wish we were writing "Cat in the Hat". Don't make coding a measure of ego. Just make things work in a simple fashion.

Developers don't want to document code, (I love documented code personally, I'm not that selfish). So don't write code that only you can understand/read. Write `Cat in the Hat` code.

We all know you are **J.R.R. Tolken** (in your head). Remember you will have nothing to prove with bug free code.

Another reason for the Metaphor.

Don't overkill the reader spread the wealth. If you work with a group of people and all of them have to change that same a large file, you are will probably putting yourself into `git` merge hell.

> Everyone loves rebasing.

-> Said no one ever!

TL;DR
Focus on readability. Spread your code and helper over multiple lines and files as much as you can. Don't throw 8 or 9 classes in a single file, It makes the code hard to read and harder to maintain. If you have a large condition code or loop, consider changing them to Lambdas if the language supports it. Utilities functions should be considered a great avenue to increase code readability. Avoid heavy nesting.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but your analogy is a bit lost on me. Are you saying it's better to spread your code over multiple lines, and have less words on each line?

Comment: Spread code and helper over multiple lines and files as much as you can. Focus on readability. Don't throw 8 or 9 classes in a single file. It makes the code hard to read and harder to maintain. If you have a large condition code or loops. Turn them into utilities. Avoid heavy nesting. Please let me know if this helps explain it.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit that into your answer, as that would make it clearer what you mean.

Comment: I used the script for Jackie Brown as a yardstick for modular z/OS COBOL programs. You know, for cocktail party banter...

Comment: "make sense to a 5 year old whenever we can." - for real world problems that pay the bills, this is rarely possible, and is aiming for the wrong thing

Comment: It's all about perspective. Most solutions to real world problems are simple. As humans we tend to over complicate simple things. Most calculus is dirived from basic simple math analyzed in a different perspective.

Comment: @whatsisname There's a difference between something being impossible and something being a bad goal. Even though making sense to a 5 year old is rarely achievable, by adopting that goal to the greatest degree possible, the result tends to be far, far better than the result of not adopting the goal, even if the goal is never quite achieved

Comment: "Both can be understood by a 5 year olds...." Not commonly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative view: you are asking about how to limit file size. My opinion is that there are many factors that make large code files very problematic. Sometimes the code file is huge but its content are well clustered and extremely clean code, so that the size does not cause any significant problems. I have seen lots of files that are very readable despite the high LOC.

Instead of tapping into LOC metric, I would rather think about using the history data to understand how often the code gets broken in those large files. Usually the reason for that is that the developers do not have time to patience to check the relevant other places in the same file and make the change with "quick fix" mentality without enough understanding.

The bigger danger is the presence of copy-paste code. Copy-paste coding naturally also speeds up the LOC growth. I think eliminating copy-paste is even more imporant than keeping LOC below some magic number. In addition to pure copy-paste, there is also a second danger in the big files: overlapping functionality. The bigger the file is, the more likely you end up reimplementing some snippet that is already in some other section of the same file.

So, as long as **bug fix ratio** (ratio of bug fix commits to all commits) is low for the larger files, the situation is tolerable. Please try `git log` for it and skim through how many of the commits are related to errors. Or use a tool that can automatically analyze and visualize it, e.g. [Softagram](https://softagram.com).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see any limit beyond practicalities imposed by version control, compilers, IDEs, language features, etc. Yet those practicalities do matter.

So it's relative to those practicalities as I see it. I remember being infuriated some decades back looking at codebases that frequently had C source files with over 20,000 LOC, but in hindsight, the biggest source of my frustration is that they often defined static file scope variables that were visible to those 20,000+ lines of code. It had to do with the extremely wide variable scope that I was getting so frustrated debugging such code, testing it, and trying to reason about it. The other is that there was a lot of toe-stepping just due to the version control tools we were using (SVN back then) which made merge conflicts especially painful as multiple developers modified the same source file. If we didn't use such file-scope globals and different version control tools, I wouldn't have found it nearly as problematic to have huge source files. The IDEs were already good enough back then in the 90s to quickly find relevant symbols without scrolling through these monstrous source files.

It's all relative as I see it. I've gone increasingly pragmatic over the years (at least in relative terms) and I recommend people do the same. There might be a real problem behind a big source file but narrow down what they actually are rather than just, "big source file is bad!" At least our persuasive factor with our team improves if we can pinpoint what's truly causing us grief. You know, I heard a wise quote one time in Star Trek that only a Sith lord deals in absolutes (JK, I know it's Star Wars but I have a slightly sadistic enjoyment of making some programmer types uncomfortable with blasphemous technical inaccuracies).

Another thing for me at least in languages like C and C++ with their compilation and linkage models is that the cheapest way to reduce build times tends to be in reducing the number of compilation units involved. Of course we still probably want more than one for a large codebase to allow parallel builds, but there is at least an argument in favor of reduced build times and improved productivity with such compilers to favor somewhat larger source files, especially if we can avoid some of the issues I've found problematic above like file scope statics.  There are those types of practicalities to consider, depending on your tools, and practices, as to whether it is desirable to have larger or smaller source files. In C++, I've found even through extensive use of precompiled headers (which do help a lot) that it can help, just as much, not to favor a style that leads to thousands upon thousands of compilation units by, say, putting every single class implementation in a separate pair of header and source files. But again that's very tailored to our use cases, our tools, processes, and what we find beneficial, and may not apply to everyone else. It's all relative at the end of the day as I see it. We're not dealing with absolutes here.

It is definitely easier to deal with absolutes, especially when starting out. "i" before "e" except after "c", even if that sometimes produces 'wierd' results. But it's all relative as I see it, and there are countless exceptions in the real world. It tends to help to try to focus on the most painful and immediate problems at hand as specifically as possible, in the same way that anyone tackling performance-critical code can benefit from the specifics that making a profiler their best friend can provide. The appreciation of nuance is the key to appreciating the benefits of favoring relatives rather than absolutes.